# Run Piranha cms from source code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, piranha-cms

I am trying to run Piranha CMS from source code (downloaded from Git).

[image: C:...\TemplateSite > Web.config]

1. I opened the code in Visual Studio 2012 and compiled it successfully.
2. Changed the database connection string to local host
3. Tried to run the code and received following error:

*This item does not support previewing*

[image: output: show output from build]

I am not able to find any help on how to run Piranha-cms from code.

Answer (score 0):

Before running against source code, decide what branch you're after.

The master branch you have is the current development version and is inconsistent to the documentation. It may also change until released causing issues with your project.

The branch 2.2.1 is the released version and 2.2.2 is the upcoming patch.

Now back to your issue. I have never verified the master branch with VS2012 as I only have 2013. From what I've read there are some issues with MVC 5 & VS2012. Have you managed to get other projects working with MVC 5 in your VS?